# How to fire custom validation attribute before executes action in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a custom CNPJ attribute class to validade a speciefic property in my model class.

```
[Required]       
[CNPJ(ErrorMessage = "Invalid input")]
public string SupplierIdentification { get; set; }
```

My CNPJ Attribute class:

```
public class CNPJAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var cnpj = Convert.ToString(value);
            if (SessionCompanyRepository.ValidaCnpj(cnpj))
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
                return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Ok, when i submit with a null SupplierIdentification  in my view the [Required] fires even before the action of the submit button is called. When i put some invalid SupplierIdentification, the action is fired and the (ModelState.IsValid) check the CNPJAttribute result. I would like to fire the [CNPJ] attribute class before i go to the action, like the [Required] attribute.

Suggestions?
Thanks.

EDIT:
My 'root' view:

```
 @(Html.Telerik()
      .Grid<DocumentModel>()
      .BindTo((List<DocumentModel>)ViewData["documents"])
      .Name("DocumentGrid").EnableCustomBinding(true)
      .DataBinding(x =>
          x.Server()
              .Insert("InsertDocument", "Client")
              .Delete("DeleteTempDocument", "Client"))
      .DataKeys(a => a.Add(c => c.IDDocument)
          .RouteKey("idDocument"))
      .Editable(a => a.Mode(GridEditMode.InForm)
          .TemplateName("AddDocumentModel")
          .InsertRowPosition(GridInsertRowPosition.Top))
      .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().Text("Add Document"))
      .Columns(c =>
               {
                   c.Bound(column => column.IDDocument).Visible(false);
                   c.Bound(column => column.SupplierIdentification);
                   c.Bound(column => column.SupplierName);                     
                   c.Command(command => command.Delete());
               }))
```

My view inside the EditorTemplate folder:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IDDocument)
 <b>@Html.Label("CPF/CNPJ:")</b>
                        <div>
                             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SupplierIdentification)                               
                              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SupplierIdentification)

<b>@Html.Label("Razão Social:")</b>
                        <div>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SupplierName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SupplierName)
 }
```

And my controller:

```
 public ActionResult InsertDocument(DocumentModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Documents"] == null)
            {
                ViewData["documents"] =
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Documents"] = new List<DocumentModel>();
            }

            model.IDDocument = Util.IDDocument;
            DocumentSessionRepository.Insert(model);
            ViewData["documents"] = DocumentSessionRepository.AllDocuments();

            return RedirectToAction("AddDocument");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("AddDocument");
    }
```

Comment: The validation attributes are always executed before the Action. You are probably doing something wrong in your Controller. Please post the code for your Action, and your View.

Comment: Is the AddDocument action supposed to pass your model to the EditorTemplate? Why are you using ViewData? You're not even passing a model to your View.

Comment: @ataravati I use the viewdata to bind a grid in the AddDocument view

Comment: You are using ViewData to pass the model to your view? That is so wrong. ViewData is supposed to be used to pass small extra data that is not part of your model. The validation rules created by data annotation attributes won't work that way. What model is your EditorTemplate using then?

Comment: Are any of your Views strongly-typed?

Comment: @ataravati Its because i have a empty grid, and the user insert rows that are stored in a session, after the user insert all the rows that he needs, he submit those rows to the repository. And yes, my editortemplate view is strongly typed to the DocumentModel class.

Comment: @ataravati , you said that the validation rules created by data annotation attributes wont work. It is valid for the Required attribute too? Because the required attribute works.

Comment: You could still pass an empty list (`new List<DocumentModel>()`) as a model. That's the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Anyway, my guess is that the problem has something to do with the Telerik Grid you are using. Is the EditorTemplate used as a partial view by the Grid?

Comment: @ataravati i pass a (List<DocumentModel>)ViewData["documents"]). If i pass an empty list, when the user insert a new row the grid will rebind and the data of 'older' rows will be lost.

Comment: @ataravati yes, it is a partial view. But i cant understand why the Required attribute wich is included in the DataAnnotation works, and if i make a custom attribute it not work in the same way.

Comment: In the Action that's used to read the data you can set the get the list from the Session, and return it (or just a new list, if there's nothing in the Session).

Comment: It could be that the Required attribute is not being fired either. You get the Required error message, because the field is not nullable in the database, and the default validation error of the entity framework is being fired.

Comment: You can test it by creating an Edit Action with a regular Edit View, and see if the custom validation works that way or not.

Answer (score 2):

this [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC-3) looks like an answer to your question if you want to use client side validation.

If this isn't what you want you can also look at the [OnActionExecuting() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), which executes before an action method in a controller

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the question. It should have been posted as a comment.